# Как создать текстовую игру в PYTHON?

Tags: python-3.x, разработка-игр, text

1. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто с чего начинает, чтобы создать текстовую 
   игру в PYTHON 3!? (прим. План, алгоритмы, или еще что то...)
2. И что вообще это такое текстовая игра, как она класифицируется?
3. Если можно какой нибудь код текстовой игры и пояснить, что да как устроено в ней!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: так там же Python/Ren'Py, да и еще и 2, а я просил только на Python 3

Comment: 2. текстовая игра - игра, взаимодействие пользователя с которой, ограничено текстовым вводом-выводом

Answer (score 0):

Ответы на ваши вопросы, скорее всего, получатся слишком объёмными и пространными. Предлагаю Вам поискать в Сети книгу Эла Свейгарта "Invent your own computer games with Python", в которой автор на простых примерах объясняет как создавать игры, начиная с простых текстовых и заканчивая играми с использованием графики при помощи сторонней библиотеки PyGame.